# How to make sortable div in jQuery ui

Tags: jquery, html, user-interface, jquery-ui-sortable

I have created some divs and now I want them to be sortable. I am generating the divs using php for loop. When I use sortable only the ui elements or radio buttons are sorted and nothing happens as expected.Following is how I am generating divs

```
<?php $questionNo = 1; foreach($english as $eng) : ?>

            <div  class="hov" id="qblock" questionID="<?php echo $eng['id']; ?>" >
                <span><?php echo $questionNo . '. '. $eng['question_desc'];  ?></span> <br/>
                <input  type="radio" name="testyourselfques<?php echo $questionNo; ?>" value="<?php echo $eng['option1'];?>" /> <span class="options"><?php echo $eng['option1'];?></span><br/>
                <input  type="radio" name="testyourselfques<?php echo $questionNo; ?>" value="<?php echo $eng['option2'];?>" /> <span class="options"><?php echo $eng['option2'];?></span><br/>
                <input  type="radio" name="testyourselfques<?php echo $questionNo; ?>" value="<?php echo $eng['option3'];?>" /> <span class="options"><?php echo $eng['option3'];?></span><br/>
                <input  type="radio" name="testyourselfques<?php echo $questionNo; ?>" value="<?php echo $eng['option4'];?>" /> <span class="options"><?php echo $eng['option4'];?></span><br/>
                <img id="q<?php echo $questionNo;?>wrong" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/images/verdict/wrong.png" height="40" width="40" style="display:none;"><img id="q<?php echo $questionNo;?>correct" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/images/verdict/correct.png" height="40" width="40" style="display:none;"><img id="q<?php echo $questionNo;?>unattempted" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/images/verdict/unattempted.png" height="40" width="40" style="display:none;"><br/>
                <span id="correctans<?php echo $questionNo;?>" style="font-size:17px;display:none;">Correct ans. : <?php echo $eng['answer'];?></span>
                <input type="hidden" id="rightanswer<?php echo $questionNo; ?>" value="<?php echo $eng['answer'];?>" />

            </div>
            <br/><br/>


            <?php $questionNo++; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

And for making those sortable I am using the following code.. but it is not working...

```
$("div#qblock").sortable();
```

How this can be fixed ????????????

Comment: Try `$('.hov').sortable()`, you should not duplicate ID and I think `$('div#qblock')` would return just 1 element.

Comment: You're generating multiple `div`s with the same `id`.  That is not valid HTML, `id`s must be unique within a document.

Comment: $('.hov').sortable(); is not working... can you please find any other way to do so... @Vega